Lower bound on the probability that the number of occurrences from a set of pairwise independent random events is 1?
I am following an online lecture series and the lecturer leaves proving the following statement as an exercise.
The statement
Let $A_1,\dots,A_m$ be pairwise independent random events with $\mathbb{P}[A_i]=p$ for all $i$, and define $T = \sum_{i=1}^m {I}_{A_{i}}$, where $I_{A_i}$ is the indicator function for $A_i$. Denote $\mu = \mathbb{E}[T]$.
Given that $1/4 \leq \mu \leq 1/2$, show  that
$$\mathbb{P}[T =1] \geq 1/8.$$
What I’ve tried
I’ve tried to use Chebyshev’s inequality to show this (as the lecturer was talking about it at the time, but I’m not sure it’s the approach they have in mind).
In particular, Chebyshev tells us
$$ \mathbb{P}[T \notin [\mu - 2\sigma, \mu + 2\sigma]] \leq 1/4,$$
where $\sigma$ is the standard deviation of $T$. We know that $\mathrm{Var}(T) = m p (1-p)$ (by pairwise independence and some algebra). So $\mathrm{Var}(T) \geq mp = \mu$, meaning that $\sigma \geq \sqrt{\mu}$. Putting this together, we have
$$\mathbb{P}[T \notin [\mu - 2\sqrt{\mu}, \mu + 2\sqrt{\mu}]] \leq 1/4.$$
Using the fact that $\mu \leq 1/2$ we can now obtain
$$\mathbb{P}[T \notin [1/2 - 2\sqrt{1/2}, 1/2 + 2\sqrt{1/2}]] \leq 1/4.$$
Or, in other words
$$\mathbb{P}[T \leq 1] \geq 3/4.$$
At this point my next idea was to use the fact that $\mu \geq 1/4$, to argue that $\mathbb{P}[T = 0]$ can’t be too large, and then subtract this to obtain the desired bound.
The issue with this is that I can write down a binomial distribution (which is obviously pairwise independent) which has $\mu=1/4$ and $\mathbb{P}[T=0]=3/4$, meaning the bound I’ve given above doesn’t seem to be tight enough for this to work.
I’d really appreciate some help/suggestions!

A binomial distribution with $\mu=\frac14$ has parameters $n, p=\frac1{4n}$ in which case you would have $P(T=1)=n\frac{(4n-1)^{n-1}}{(4n)^n}>0.1947>0.125$

Sorry perhaps I wasn’t clear enough. I wasn’t saying that such a binomial is a counter example. I was trying to say that since $P(T=0) = 3/4$ for this distribution, I can’t hope to use $P(T\geq 1) \geq 3/4$ to get a bound for $P(T=1)$. The approach I was thinking of was using the fact that $P(T = 1) = P(T\leq 1) - P(T=0)$. Does this clear things up?

Basically if I could show that $P(T=0) \leq 5/8$, then we’d be done, but this isn’t true (the binomial distribution is a counter example). That’s where I’m stuck.

What does pairwise random events mean?

Ah, that's a typo, I meant pairwise independent. By pairwise independent I mean that for any $i, j$, we have that $P(A_i \cap A_j) = P(A_i)P(A_j)$. In words, any pair of events is independent.

Directly from the Markov inequality you can get $P[T\geq 2] \leq E[T]/2 \leq 1/4$. I believe Chebyshev can give a better bound $P[T\geq 2] \leq 2/9$, so $P[T=0]+P[T=1]\geq 7/9$.
